# How can I use solr handlers internally?

Tags: solr, search-engine, solrj

So assume I want to implement custom morelikethis(or autosuggest) experience by merging output of two different morelikethis handler configurations. 
Pseudo code could look like

```
 class MyMoreLikeThis extends SearchHanlder {
      def process(reqBuilder) {
        val mlt1 = reBuilder.getComponent("/mlt1");
        val mlt2 = reBuilder.getComponent("/mlt2");
        val rb1 = reqBuilder.copy()
        val rb2 = reqBuilder.copy()
        reqBuilder.results = mlt1.process(rb1).getResults ++ mlt1.process(rb2).getResults 
      }
    }
```

Or probably I can use solrj API to access solr from inside.

How can I do this? Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the below blog posts that has detailed explanation on how to achieve merging results from different queries similar to the problem that you are talking about,

- [Custom Search Handler
  Idea#1](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/02/solr-custom-search-requesthandler.html)
- [Custom Search Handler
  Idea#2](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/09/multithreaded-proxy-solr-search-handler.html)

The blog is authored by a former colleague of mine who has number of years expertise with Search & Information Retrieval.

Comment: I like second idea, since it suggests use of convinient solr4j API. But it adds serialization overhead and can lead to recursion over http.
First idea is more about how to write CustomComponent rather than how to combine solr components...